# Maven dependency conflict (Wicket + Spring + Hibernate / ASM)

Tags: hibernate, maven, dependencies, wicket

I am currently upgrading a Wicket project from wicket version 1.4.2 to 6.4.0. The migration for wicket components/page went well, but I encounter an issue with projet's dependencies.

This is a old project, relying on old technologies and private framework. My company framework cannot be upgraded (for the moment), so I have to deal with its specificities.

When I deploy my webapp to Glassfish, I get the following error:

```
ERROR - ContextLoader              - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL  [jar:file:/home/company/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-modules/mainProject-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/daoProject-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/dataContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
```

This seems to be due to ASM, included in both Wicket and Spring using different versions.

There is parts of `<dependencies>` from my poms:

Main project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>privateFramework</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>daoProject</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apach.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

DAO project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>privateFramework</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Private framework:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

There is the `$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=asm` output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ immatriculation ---
[INFO] my.company:mainProject:war:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- my.company:privateFramework:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |        +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO]       \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO]          \- (asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.3)
```

Is there a "best practice" to resolve such kind of dependencies conflicts? I tried several thing (excluding `asm` from `privateFramework`, force asm to 3.3.1 using `dependencyManagement`, ...) but I was not able to get it working.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try setting the scope of `cglib:cglib` to `provided` (so that it will not be added to the WAR file), and use `cglib:cglib-nodep` instead. This distribution of cglib has a 'shaded' version (base package changed) of asm embedded, voiding the conflict.

Add this to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```